# Parse JSON to excel worksheet by JSONConverter

Tags: excel, vba

I created a VBA code that enables me to get a string from a website. The string looks like that (json format)

```json
[
   {
      "CD":151,
      "nID":111,
      "sNM":"PNAME1",
      "GDR":"MA",
      "RGN":"MM",
      "reID":1,
      "status":"RSB",
      "NTY":"EG",
      "CLNUM":1,
      "CLNM":"THIR",
      "YER":2022,
      "SCHOD":1718,
      "STID":2,
      "THNM":"BRYYY",
      "SCHNO":"HTBAN",
      "rCD":6,
      "schooL_TYPE":1,
      "SGT":1,
      "CLCD":3,
      "NG1":1,
      "NG2":2,
      "YCOD":null,
      "general":10,
      "special":1,
      "naT_ID":1,
      "GDR_ID":1,
      "sGCOD":8,
      "sTTY":1,
      "obNM":"NTF",
      "obID":0,
      "STYN":"NTHMY",
      "PSNUM":null
   },
   {
      "CD":153,
      "nID":222,
      "sNM":"ALIIKK",
      "GDR":"MA",
      "RGN":"MM",
      "reID":1,
      "status":"RSB",
      "NTY":"EG",
      "CLNUM":1,
      "CLNM":"THIR",
      "YER":2022,
      "SCHOD":1718,
      "STID":2,
      "THNM":"SYYYYY",
      "SCHNO":"HTBAN",
      "rCD":6,
      "schooL_TYPE":1,
      "SGT":1,
      "CLCD":3,
      "NG1":1,
      "NG2":2,
      "YCOD":null,
      "general":10,
      "special":1,
      "naT_ID":1,
      "GDR_ID":1,
      "sGCOD":8,
      "sTTY":1,
      "obNM":"NTF",
      "obID":0,
      "STYN":"NTHMY",
      "PSNUM":null
   }
]
```

I am trying to store the data into a collection and arrays
This is my try but I am confused about the line of setting the collection

```
Dim json As Object, col As Collection
    Set json = JSONConverter.ParseJson(sResp)
    Set col = json("CD")
    Dim a, i As Long
        ReDim a(1 To col.Count, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To col.Count
        'a(i, 1) = col.Item(i)("")
    Next i
```

The string should have two persons' data. How can I pares all the data included into two rows?

I got an error `Dictionary Key Not Found` at this line of `JSONConverter` module

Comment: Suppose I deleted the brackets [] then I have only dictionaries. Is there a way to separate each dictionary information in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()

    Dim sResp
    sResp = "[{'CD':151,'nID':111,'sNM':'PNAME1','GDR':'MA','RGN':'MM','reID':1,'status':'RSB','NTY':'EG','CLNUM':1,'CLNM':'THIR','YER':2022,'SCHOD':1718,'STID':2,'THNM':'BRYYY','SCHNO':'HTBAN','rCD':6,'schooL_TYPE':1,'SGT':1,'CLCD':3,'NG1':1,'NG2':2,'YCOD':null,'general':10,'special':1,'naT_ID':1,'GDR_ID':1,'sGCOD':8,'sTTY':1,'obNM':'NTF','obID':0,'STYN':'NTHMY','PSNUM':null},{'CD':153,'nID':222,'sNM':'ALIIKK','GDR':'MA','RGN':'MM','reID':1,'status':'RSB','NTY':'EG','CLNUM':1,'CLNM':'THIR','YER':2022,'SCHOD':1718,'STID':2,'THNM':'SYYYYY','SCHNO':'HTBAN','rCD':6,'schooL_TYPE':1,'SGT':1,'CLCD':3,'NG1':1,'NG2':2,'YCOD':null,'general':10,'special':1,'naT_ID':1,'GDR_ID':1,'sGCOD':8,'sTTY':1,'obNM':'NTF','obID':0,'STYN':'NTHMY','PSNUM':null}]"
    sResp = Replace(sResp, "'", Chr(34))
   
    Dim data As Object, rec As Object, key, fields, arData
    Dim n As Long, m As Long, i As Long, j As Long

    Set data = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResp)
   
    fields = data(1).Keys
    m = UBound(fields) + 1
    n = data.Count ' records
    
    ' fill array
    ReDim arData(1 To n, 1 To m)
    For i = 1 To n
         For j = 1 To m
            arData(i, j) = data(i)(fields(j - 1))
         Next
    Next

    ' dump array
    With Sheet1
       .Range("A1").Resize(1, m) = fields ' header
       .Range("A2").Resize(n, m) = arData
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems the code is working well with just the example I posted but not with the original json (I got the same error which is KEYNOTFOUNDERROR). It seems the json is not totally correct and there are some errors at some parts. I used the website https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to fix it, but I need to do all the task using VBA as I am scraping a website and the response is just part of the code

Comment: @YasserKhalil I cant reproduce the error but try adding check that keys exist `If data(i).Exists(fields(j - 1)) Then :  arData(i, j) = data(i)(fields(j - 1)) :  End If`

Comment: This trick doesn't solve the error message and even if it solves the error message, I expect not to have results. Is there a special way to send you the original code to have a look? This is my fb `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100081886906209`

Comment: Without you posting an example of your "broken" JSON it's difficult to knw what fixes might work here.

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you join me to a discussion?

Comment: On what topic ?

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong. The converter also accepts square brackets as the first element, a collection. The suggested additional brackets would not work either, because they create an invalid JSON.

Now CDP1802 has already answered, but I also looked for a correct solution because of my wrong statement (I deleted it so no one else would see it as the truth):

```
Sub TestJSON()
  
  Dim sResp As String
  Dim json As Collection
  Dim col As Dictionary
  Dim key As Variant
  Dim dicts As Long
  Dim row As String
  
  sResp = "[{""CD"":151,""nID"":111,""sNM"":""PNAME1"",""GDR"":""MA"",""RGN"":""MM"",""reID"":1,""status"":""RSB"",""NTY"":""EG"",""CLNUM"":1,""CLNM"":""THIR"",""YER"":2022,""SCHOD"":1718,""STID"":2,""THNM"":""BRYYY"",""SCHNO"":""HTBAN"",""rCD"":6,""schooL_TYPE"":1,""SGT"":1,""CLCD"":3,""NG1"":1,""NG2"":2,""YCOD"":null,""general"":10,""special"":1,""naT_ID"":1,""GDR_ID"":1,""sGCOD"":8,""sTTY"":1,""obNM"":""NTF"",""obID"":0,""STYN"":""NTHMY"",""PSNUM"":null},{""CD"":153,""nID"":222,""sNM"":""ALIIKK"",""GDR"":""MA"",""RGN"":""MM"",""reID"":1,""status"":""RSB"",""NTY"":""EG"",""CLNUM"":1,""CLNM"":""THIR"",""YER"":2022,""SCHOD"":1718,""STID"":2,""THNM"":""SYYYYY"",""SCHNO"":""HTBAN"",""rCD"":6,""schooL_TYPE"":1,""SGT"":1,""CLCD"":3,""NG1"":1,""NG2"":2,""YCOD"":null,""general"":10,""special"":1,""naT_ID"":1,""GDR_ID"":1,""sGCOD"":8,""sTTY"":1,""obNM"":""NTF"",""obID"":0,""STYN"":""NTHMY"",""PSNUM"":null}]"
  Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sResp)
  
  For dicts = 1 To json.Count
    Set col = json(dicts)
    For Each key In col.Keys()
      'Debug.Print key & ":" & col(key) & ", "
      row = row & col(key) & Chr(9)
    Next key
    Debug.Print row
    row = ""
  Next dicts
End Sub
```